# How to put 2 forms on one page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am trying to place 2 HTML forms on the same page, then use `JavaScript` to control the target `.php` file they submit to, based on which `submit` button is pressed.

At the moment, it's sending to the correct php/email address, but also taking the user away from the page - which is what I want to prevent.

Any help would be appreciated. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <form class="form" id="ajax-contact-form" action="multi/sendmail.php">
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
        <input type="text" name="contact_name" id="contact_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
        <input name="contact_email" id="contact_email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <textarea name="contact_message" id="contact_message" placeholder="Message" rows="8" class="form-control" required></textarea>
    <div class="controls send">
      <button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg" value="Submit1" id="submit2" onClick="mainform">Send</button>
      <div class="loading"></div>
      <div class="results"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<!--FORM 2-->
<div class="col-md-6">
  <form class="form2" id="ajax-contact-form2" action="multi/sendmail2.php">
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
        <input type="text" name="contact_name" id="contact_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
        <input name="contact_email" id="contact_email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <textarea name="contact_message" id="contact_message" placeholder="Message" rows="8" class="form-control" required></textarea>
    <div class="controls send">
      <button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg" value="Submit2" id="submit2" onClick="form2">Send</button>
      <div class="loading"></div>
      <div class="results"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<!--/FORM 2-->
```

And here is my JavaScript:

```
function mainform() {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.loading').show();
    $.post('multi/sendmail.php', $('.form').serialize(), function(data) {
        $('.results').html(data);
    }).success(function() {
        $('.loading').hide();
    })
}

function form2() {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.loading').show();
    $.post('multi/sendmail2.php', $('.form2').serialize(), function(data) {
        $('.results').html(data);
    }).success(function() {
        $('.loading').hide();
    })
}
```

And here is my old JavaScript, which worked:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.loading').show();
    $.post('multi/sendmail.php', $('.form').serialize(), function(data){
        $('.results').html(data);
    }).success(function(){
        $('.loading').hide();
    })
})
```

And one of the PHP files:

```
<?php
$name = isset($_REQUEST['contact_name']) ? $_REQUEST['contact_name'] : '' ;
$email = isset($_REQUEST['contact_email']) ? $_REQUEST['contact_email'] : '' ;
$message = isset($_REQUEST['contact_message']) ? $_REQUEST['contact_message'] : '' ;

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From:".$name." ".$email;

// Replace mail@website.com with your email
mail( "me@email.com", "Message from My Future Now Website",$message, $headers );
print "<strong>Form submitted successfully.</strong>";
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Simplified the question text, improved code readability

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the second place that the following lines appears to something else?

```
<div class="loading"></div>
<div class="results"></div>
```

I see both javascript functions refer to an element like it's the only one, and you have two now. If you change the second one to this:

```
<div class="results2"></div>
<div class="loading2"></div>
```

Then you can change

```
function form2(){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.loading').show();
   $.post('multi/sendmail2.php', $('.form2').serialize(), function(data){
     $('.results').html(data);
   }).success(function(){
     $('.loading').hide();
  })
}
```

to:

```
function form2(){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.loading2').show();
   $.post('multi/sendmail2.php', $('.form2').serialize(), function(data){
     $('.results2').html(data);
   }).success(function(){
     $('.loading2').hide();
  })
}
```

I think that will give you greater success. Let me know if you run into any further problems after trying such a change

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here which are preventing the functionality you want.

Your page is posting because when you call `e.preventDefault()` - I suspect you are getting a JavaScript error, indicating that `e` is `undefined`.

Because the `default` behavior of a `submit` button being `click`ed is therefore *not* being `prevent`ed - it occurs... and the default behavior is a full-page post to the server. This is why you're being taken away from your page.

There are 2 ways you can solve for this easily:

**1. Solution 1: Just add the `event` parameter back in**

```
function mainform(e) { ... }
function form2(e) { ... }
```

This will simply fix the JavaScript error you currently have, and allow your `e.preventDefault()` to work.

However - you are using jQuery on your page already - so I suggest that you maintain consistency with your tools - and use jQuery's event binding syntax. This is how your *original* JavaScript was written - and you can now go back to it.

**2. Solution 2: Reintroduce jQuery**

1. Change the `ID` of your your *first* form's submit button to `ID="submit1'`. Currently both buttons have the same name, which is invalid HTML and may cause issues.
2. Remove the `onclick=` binding syntax from *both* `button` elements.
3. Update your JavaScript as follows:

*New JavaScript:*

```
$('#submit1').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.loading').show();
    $.post('multi/sendmail.php', $('.form').serialize(), function(data) {
        $('.results').html(data);
    }).success(function() {
        $('.loading').hide();
    })
});

$('#submit2').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.loading').show();
    $.post('multi/sendmail2.php', $('.form2').serialize(), function(data) {
        $('.results').html(data);
    }).success(function() {
        $('.loading').hide();
    })
});
```

Note that we still added back in the `e` to each `function()` call - exactly as in **Solution 1**.

If this doesn't work for you - feel free to comment and ask for more help.